# Confusing behavior of re module regarding tabs

Tags: python, regex

As a novice programmer I recently stumbled upon a strange behaviour of my implementation of regex.  Via parsing an excel-file, I fill a dictionary with keys of this structure:

```
1   21555159    A   T   G   P
15  2626264985  C   A   R   Q
X   515151  G   C   D   W
…
```

The six entries are tab separated and I need them in this form for a query. 
Later on, I parse another file, where the said keys should be found at the start of some lines (exactly looking as above) with this rather clumsy regular expression:

```
match = re.search("(^.{1,2}\t\d+\t\D\t\D\t\D\t\D)", line_iterater)
```

Then - match.group() - provides me, for example, this output...

```
1\t21555159\tA\tT\tG\tP
```

...which, of course, doesn’t match with the key in the dictionary, so I cannot access the corresponding items.

Question: Why is this behaviour of the `re` module that I get a ‘\t’ for a tab ‘    ‘ 
or what’s wrong with my understanding of it.

(My naïve remedy was to chance all tabs in the keys with `\t`)

Comment: What's the problem? Please show a **complete** example that demonstrates the behaviour *and* show us what would be your expected output.

Comment: use the builtin [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in python ... re-implementing csv parsing is a pet peeve of mine that everybody tries to do and always gets something wrong. Its been done to death, use the builtin library!

Comment: Pro Tip: Use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for parsing csv files, instead of attempting to parse it with RE. This not only saves you the work of writing REs and dealing with match objects, but will work even for special cases like quoted values in columns.

Comment: Ah, I did parse the ecxel-file with xlrd (and some regex to extrakt the 4 characters from cell entries). With this I could create an uniqe string that I use for a database-query and as a Key in an dict. But, as it stand, seemingly I have to use the escape sequence \t in this key-string to make the dict searchable with the results i later gain from re.search a database outputfile. But I will look to replace this second search with the CSV module. Thank you all, that was my first question and I'm still lerning to ask good questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The output,

```
1\t21555159\tA\tT\tG\tP
```

is correct. Python represents tab characters with the [escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) `\t`. And, as Cilyan, Pykler, and l4mpi have already said, it would be easier and less error-prone to parse tab-delineated values using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

others

Comment: O.k. My key-strings have tap characters. So the correct response would indeed be to replace them with the escape sequence \t to make them simple searchable. Good so.

Comment: If `key = '1\t21555159\tA\tT\tG\tP'`, then you can test if a `line` starts with this key using `line.startswith(key)`. I'm not sure why you would need to replace anything.

Comment: Just because I parse the second file, extract a substring (in this form above) und than test if this substring matches any entry in my dictionary, that I build before. But there were no escape seq in the key-string, just taps ^^ 
I thought re would handle me the exact/literal string that it matches, I stand corrected (It delivers more than literal ;)